# Reacts useEffects exhaustive deps only trigger to create component will unmount functionality

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, eslint-plugin-react-hooks

I am trying to implement a useEffect callback to dispatch an action before unmounting a component. The point of this action is to store the last state of my component so I can resume from that state the next time this component is loaded. I only want this callback to be triggered on unmount.

When trying to use an empty dependency array for my useEffect, the 'exhaustive-deps' rule in reacts recommended 'eslint-plugin-react-hooks' demands I include the value I am trying to persist. This results in the effect and therefore action being triggered every time I store state.

Is there a better way to handle this situation then disabling eslint for this line?

Here is what I want:

```
...
const [value, setValue] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        storeValueAction(value);
    };
}, []);
...
```

The way eslint-plugin-react-hooks wants it and results in the action being dispatched on every state change:

```
...
const [value, setValue] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        storeValueAction(value);
    };
}, [value, storeValueAction]);
...
```

Is there something other than useEffect I should be using for this?

Comment: `storeValueAction` is a prop right?

Comment: Yes, storeValueAction is a prop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if you implement it in the current manner and disable the eslint rule, the expected result won't be correct since the state value dispatched on unmount will be the state value during the initial mount due to closure.

For such a case, you can make use of useRef along with useEffect to achieve a desired result. Once you do that you can safely disable the eslint rule being assured that you code won't result in an unexpected behaviour

```
const [value, setValue] = useState('');
const valueRef = useRef(value);

useEffect(() => {
   valueRef.current = value;
}, [value]);

useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        storeValueAction(valueRef.current);
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, []);
```

Comment: Do you have a solution without disabling the rule?

Comment: You might be able to add `valueRef` and `storeValueAction` to the dependency array, since both those are references that don't change across renders.

Comment: Thank you. I think this will work. I had only been using refs before to access dom nodes.

Comment: no need for `useEffect` for `valueRef.current = value`. This can be put directly in the function.

Comment: @Julian Eslint rule isn't perfectly polished to work for every case and is not a strict rule, you can choose to disable the rule when you know are perfectly right. However in the above case you can choose to add storeValueAction and valueRef to dependency array as Francisco pointed out provided you aren't creating the storeValueAction function on each render